# IOUSBDevice::ReEnumerateDevice() - how to use this?

Tags: macos, usb, driver, iokit, kernel-extension

I'm calling `IOUSBDevice::ReEnumerateDevice()` in a kernel extension on OS X. This is supposed to look like a full un-plug/plug-in. I don't really want a full un-plug/plug-in for this USB device, but that seems to be the only way to convince OS X to re-`probe` the device for a different driver.

Anyhoo, when I call `IOUSBDevice::ReEnumerateDevice()`, the `IOUSBDevice` itself is actually `free`'d and a completely new one is created. This is a problem because it looks just like the hardware device itself actually being unplugged and then plugged-in. I need to do something very different in both of those cases.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there any way to determine whether or not a brand new `IOUSBDevice` that just appeared is appearing because of a call to `IOUSBDevice::ReEnumerate()` on a now defunct `IOUSBDevice` rather than a brand new device plug-in?

Keep in mind that what I really want to do here is just kick an existing class driver (usually `IOUSBCompositeDriver`) off of the `IOUSBDevice`. If there were an easier way of doing that that didn't corrupt `IOUSBDevice`'s internal state, I would probably do that instead. But for now it appears that I might be stuck with `IOUSBDevice::ReEnumerateDevice()`.

Comment: Have you tried calling `terminate()` on the client you're attempting to eject? I don't think that will re-initiate matching, however. What are you ultimately trying to do? Avoid requiring reboot on kext installation?

Comment: Briefly looking over the source code of `IOUSBDevice::ReEnumerateDevice()` I can't seem to make sense of your observation that the `IOUSBDevice` is `free`d. How are you determining this? Does the pointer value change? Does the result of `getRegistryEntryID()` change?

Comment: There's a release() call in the reenumerate thread function. And if you look at the IOUSBDevice ptr before and after the ReEnumerateDevice, it's different. And according to dtrace, IOUSBDevice::stop() and IOUSBDevice::free() have been called.